# Can mutate_at name a variable according to a wrapped function name? (dplyr + rlang question)

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, rlang

I want to create a function that mutates all variables specified in ... with a particular metric specified by the metric argument. I use mutate_at in the function and want it to rename the variable with "var.functionname". The function is as follows:

```
seasonAggregator <- function(.data, ..., metric = "sum") {
  # all variables in ... will be accumulated
  metric <- sym(metric)
  name <- ensym(metric)
  print(paste0("Metric for accumulation was: ", metric))
  .data <- .data %>% mutate_at(vars(...), .funs = list(!!name := metric)) # HERE IS THE ISSUE
  return(.data)
}
```

How can I specify the function in the metric argument as such, that the mutate_at uses the name of the function to rename the variables?

Best Moritz!

Comment: Might be helpful to show an example `data.frame` with the expected results post function.

Comment: does it work if you use `rlang::list2` instead of `list` ? `list` as a base function doesn't support `!!` notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Moody_Mudskipper is correct. You want to use `rlang::list2()` which supports quasiquotation. Also, you probably want `summarize_at`, not `mutate_at`, since you're accumulating via `sum`.

```
seasonAggregator <- function(.data, ..., metric = "sum") {
  ## all variables in ... will be accumulated
  print(paste0("Metric for accumulation was: ", metric))
  .data <- .data %>% 
      summarize_at(vars(...), .funs = rlang::list2(!!metric := sym(metric)))
  return(.data)
}

seasonAggregator( mtcars, mpg, cyl )
# [1] "Metric for accumulation was: sum"
#   mpg_sum cyl_sum
# 1   642.9     198

seasonAggregator( mtcars, mpg, cyl, metric="mean" )
# [1] "Metric for accumulation was: mean"
#   mpg_mean cyl_mean
# 1 20.09062   6.1875
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, I'll try it right away. However, I don't want to summarize, because I actually want to use cumsum and cummean to aggregate the data consecutively. It's soccer data that aggregates statistics after each matchday.

Comment: Hi Artem; can I ask you one more question, you seemed to know rlang very well.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317580/how-to-wrap-css-and-xpath-arguments-in-html-nodes-in-a-generic-function